# MySQL query to join columns and limit each column by a number

Tags: mysql

MySQL query

```
SELECT A FROM data WHERE A LIKE '%$term%'
|| B LIKE '%$term%' LIMIT 5 
UNION SELECT D FROM data WHERE D LIKE '%$term%' 
|| E LIKE '%$term%' LIMIT 5
```

In this I want to show data of my A column when it matches against data field from column A or B limit this number by 5 + data of my D column when it matches against data field from column D or E limit this number by 5

But in actual it shows only 5 row instead of 10. Any idea where I am wrong. Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap each of the individual queries (including the LIMIT clause) in parens. This allows a `LIMIT` clause to be applied to each individual query.

For example:

```
( SELECT A  FROM data
   WHERE A LIKE '%$term%' || B LIKE '%$term%'
   LIMIT 5
)
UNION ALL   
( SELECT D FROM data 
   WHERE D LIKE '%$term%' || E LIKE '%$term%' 
   LIMIT 5
)
```

(The only changes from your original query is the addition of the parens around each SELECT, and the use of `UNION ALL` in place of `UNION`. If we need to identify and remove duplicate rows, we use the `UNION` operator, otherwise, we use `UNION ALL`.

If you need the resultset in a particular order, add an ORDER BY clause at the end of the statement, following the last close paren.

Answer (score 1):

Union removes any of duplicate data while fetching the data so if above query contains records A and if below one contain a record A , in final result there will be only one records for both of them. so use UNION ALL here.

```
(SELECT A FROM data WHERE A LIKE '%$term%' ||
B LIKE '%$term%' LIMIT 5)

UNION ALL

(SELECT D FROM data WHERE 
D LIKE '%$term%' || E LIKE '%$term%' LIMIT 5)
```

Comment: No it doesn't work.

Actually first I want my A Column data to show up ---> limited by number 5 then I want my D Column data to show up ----> limited by number 5.

It's working fine so far, but just limiting the whole Column A + Column D data by 5

Comment: +1. We'd need to wrap the individual queries in parens, in order for the LIMIT clauses to apply to each query, rather than the entire set e.g. **`(SELECT ... LIMIT 5) UNION ALL (SELECT ... LIMIT 5)`**. The recommendation to use `UNION ALL` in place of `UNION` is spot on.